# Copy modified files with directory structure in linux

Tags: linux, macos, unix

How can I copy a list of files modified today with the directory structure into a new directory. As shown in the following command I want to copy all the files modified today from /dev1/Java/src into /dev2/java/src. The src folder has many sub directories.

find /dev1/Java/src -newermt 2014-06-10 > 1.txt

for f in $(cat 1.txt) ; do cp $f /dev2/Java/src; done

Comment: Try `cd /dev1/Java/src; find . -mindepth 1 -mtime -1 | cpio -pdmuv /dev2/Java/src`. Or if you prefer to use the list of files in `1.txt` try `cpio -pdmuv < 1.txt` as long as the list of file in `1.txt` is relative to `/dev1/Java/src`.

Comment: @alvits you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @alvits please post as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of `find` and `cpio` utility.

```
cd /dev1/Java/src; find . -mindepth 1 -mtime -1 | cpio -pdmuv /dev2/Java/src
```

The above command goes to the source directory and finds the list of new files relative to the source directory.

The output is read by `cpio` and copies the files into the target directory in the same structure as the source, hence the need for relative pathnames.

Answer (score 0):

Extracts the files modified within a day and copies them to the desired path.

```
find . -type f -mtime -1 -exec cp {} /path \;
```

Comment: Bit of explanation here would help the questioner understand better your answer.. "give a man a fish.. etc"